# MySQL - Get records from INNER JOIN not between dates

Tags: mysql, date, range, between

I have two tables

Accounts:

```
+------------+--------+
| accountsid | name   |
+------------+--------+
|          1 | Bob    |
|          2 | Rachel |
|          3 | Mark   |
+------------+--------+
```

Sales Orders

```
+--------------+------------+------------+--------+
| salesorderid | accountsid | so_date    | amount |
+--------------+------------+------------+--------+
|            1 |          1 | 2015-12-16 |     50 |
|            2 |          1 | 2016-01-13 |     20 |
|            3 |          2 | 2015-12-14 |     10 |
|            4 |          3 | 2016-02-14 |     35 |
+--------------+------------+------------+--------+
```

As you can see, is a 1-N relation where Accounts has many Salesorders and Salesorder has 1 Account.

I need to retrieve "old" Accounts where are not active anymore. For example, If some Account dont have Salesorder in 2016 is an inactive Account.

So, in this example the result will be ONLY Rachel.

How can i retrieve this? I think its the "opposite" of between but I cant figure how to do it...

Thanks.

PS. Despite the title I can get this without INNER JOIN.

Comment: Please, post your current code without `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to effect an anti-join, for which there are three possibilities in MySQL:

1. Using `NOT IN`:

   ```
   SELECT a.*
   FROM   Accounts a
   WHERE  a.accountsid NOT IN (
            SELECT so.accountsid
            FROM   `Sales Orders` so
            WHERE  so.so_date >= '2016-01-01'
          )
   ```
2. Using `NOT EXISTS`:

   ```
   SELECT a.*
   FROM   Accounts a
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM   `Sales Orders` so
            WHERE  so.accountsid = a.accountsid
               AND so.so_date >= '2016-01-01'
          )
   ```
3. Using an outer `JOIN`:

   ```
   SELECT a.*
   FROM   Accounts a LEFT JOIN `Sales Orders` so
       ON so.accountsid = a.accountsid
      AND so.so_date >= '2016-01-01'
   WHERE  so.accountsid IS NULL
   ```

Comment: Hi,

I will look into last example, is very interesting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to use only inner join? inner join is for cases you have data matching on two tables but in this case you don't you need to be using a subquery with either "not in" or "not exists"

Comment: you should do something like this:
select accountsid from accounts a where not exists (select 1 from sales s where s.accountsid = a.accountsid and so_date >= '2016-01-01');

Comment: Hmm thanks, i edited with "PS", I will dig more into this!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to get the ids that didn´t make any order, so get the ids that made some order and the rest of them are the ones that didn´t make orders.

It should be something like this `SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE accountsid NOT IN (SELECT accountsid FROM Sales Orders WHERE so_date > your_date)`